# Making Easing Slider Start banner depend on the day of the week

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm currently using Easing Slider Plugin in a Wordpress Project, And the Starter banner should depend on the day of the week. For example:

Sunday: banner n° 1, Monday: banner n° 2, Tuesday: banner n° 3, so on...

How could I do it?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Easing Slider Wordpress Plugin, the StartItem should be changed like this:

```
startItem: new Date().getDay()
```

That Start the Slider depending on the weekday, in Sunday it will Start with the Frist banner, Monday with the second, so on..